# Syncing clock to external midi with iPad

Tags: midi, synthesizer

I am trying to integrate the *ModStep* iPad app into my setup.  I have a *Moog Matriarch* and a *Moog Mother-32*.  What I would like to do is sequence the *Mother-32* using the *ModStep* iPad app and have the *Matriarch* use the same clock from *ModStep*.

I have successfully sequenced the *Mother-32* using *ModStep*.  This is **not** using the *Mother-32* clock (the sequencer on the *Mother-32* is **not** running).  I have tried to get the Matriarch to use the same clock.  What I have tried is setting the `assign` output on the *Mother-32* to be the sequencer clock and then patched that into the clock in on the *Matriarch*.  This results in no clock at all on the *Matriarch*, which makes sense because the sequencer on the *Mother-32* is not running.

How can I get the iPad to be the master clock for both *Mother-32* and the *Matriarch*?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but I've never used this kind of apps, how are you linking the iPad to the Mother? Adaptator toward MIDI-din or USB-MIDI, or something else?

Comment: I’m using a USB midi adapter with the Apple camera connection kit. It works well for connecting USB devices to iPad.

Comment: Neat, it works like an OTG so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that there is no THRU MIDI on the Mother-32… But there is one on the Matriarch!

Why not connecting the Matriarch to Modstep, and then connecting the Mother to the Matriarch using the THRU MIDI port of the latest (and the MIDI in of the Mother)?

As the MIDI Thru is giving a copy of the received signal, both Moogs will be fed with the clock produced by ModStep.

Comment: Thanks for this- I tried this and got a bit closer but now I think I’m having a different issue.  I could set ModStep to send on Midi channel 8 and I set the Matriarch to ignore channel 8, so everything worked- the matriarch is seeing the midi clock signal from the iPad and the Mother-32 is playing the notes—- well, most of them.  That’s the next issue I’m having- I’ve tried several apps and it always seems to be hit and miss about playing notes.  Just looping one bar has different results :(  Not sure if it is a problem with my USB adapter, but I’ll keep looking.

Comment: @SteveH.  That's a start! This is weird, the midi clock is producing a lot of signal (24 per beat if I remember well) but normally that should not saturate the midi… The easiest way to check that is to output this MIDI on a computer if you have a sound card which is accepting MIDI signals…